# R Question: How can I create a histogram with 2 variables against eachother?

Tags: r

Okay, let me be as clear as I can in my problem. I'm new to R, so your patience is appreciated. 
I want to create a histogram using two different vectors. The first vector contains a list of models (products). These models are listed as either integers, strings, or NA. I'm not exactly sure how R is storing them (I assume they're kept as strings), or if that is a relevant issue. I also have a vector containing a list of incidents pertaining to that model. So for example, one row in the dataframe might be:

```
Model    Incidents
XXX1991  7
```

How can I create a histogram where the number of incidents for each model is shown? So the histogram will look like

```
             |           =
             |           = 
Frequency of |           =
Incidents    | =         = 
             | =   =     =
             | = = = =   = 
               - - - - - - 
             Each different Model
```

Just to give a general idea.

I also need to be able to map everything out with standard deviation lines, so that it's easy to see which models are the least reliable. But that's not the main question here. I just don't want to do anything that will make me unable to use standard deviation in the future.

So far, all I really understand is how to make a histogram with the frequency marked, but for some reason, the x-axis is marked with numbers, not the models' names.

I don't really care if I have to download new packages to make this work, but I suspect that this already exists in basic R or ggplot2 and I'm just too dumb to figure it out.

Feel free to ask clarfying questions. Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, there are multiple rows of incidents listed under each model. So to add to my example earlier:

```
Model    Incidents
XXX1991  7
XXX1991  1
XXX1991  19
         3
         5
XXX1002  9
XXX1002  4
etc . . .
```

I want to add up all the incidents for a model under one label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you did not mean to leave the model blank in your example, so I filled in some values.

You can add up the number of incidents by model using `aggregate` then make the relevant plot using `barplot`.

```
## Example Data
data = read.table(text="Model    Incidents
XXX1991  7
XXX1991  1
XXX1991  19
XXX1992  3
XXX1992  5
XXX1002  9
XXX1002  4",
header=TRUE)

TAB = aggregate(data$Incidents, list(data$Model), sum) 
TAB
Group.1  x
1 XXX1002 13
2 XXX1991 27
3 XXX1992  8

barplot(TAB$x, names.arg=TAB$Group.1 )
```

[image: Barplot]

Comment: Thank you! I actually did mean to leave out the model, because some of the entries are blank. I think these were just cases where someone left a field blank when they were filling out an incident report. Thanks again!